# internal language for the 2-category of small categories

Tags: ct.category-theory, computer-science, lambda-calculus

What is the internal language of the category Cat of small categories?

I found an [article](http://www.brics.dk/RS/01/27/) by Glynn Winskel and his student Mario Jose Cáccamo about such calculus! However it is limited to a fragment of Cat. I wonder if there have been further work since the PhD thesis of Cáccamo.

http://www.brics.dk/RS/01/27/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may be interested in Harper and Licata, *2-Dimensional Directed Dependent Type Theory*, [PDF](http://dlicata.web.wesleyan.edu/pubs/lh102dtt/lh102dtt.pdf).  I did some abortive work on this [myself](http://ncatlab.org/michaelshulman/show/internal+logic+of+a+2-category) as well.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Mike. Could you please comment why you think your work on this was not successful?

Comment: I wouldn't say it wasn't successful; I just never got around to finishing it.

Comment: Sorry, Mike. I misunderstood the meaning of the word "abortive" that you used in your answer.

Comment: @Bob: Well, according to http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/abortive, the first definition is "unsuccessful", whereas the closest definition to what I meant is the third one, "imperfectly developed".  So your interpretation was quite reasonable and perhaps my word choice was poor.  (-:

Comment: This paper and your work are from the point of view of logic. But, from a computational point of view, if we see 0-cells as types and 1-cells as terms-in-context, then what are 2-cells and what are horizontal and vertical compositions of 2-cells? Thank you in advance for any light you can bring.

Comment: @Bob, I'm not a good person to ask that question; why don't you try Bob Harper or Dan Licata?